# How are special characters handled in an oData query?

Tags: javascript, sql, entity-framework, odata

How is the & symbol handled in the following query in oData?

```
/vendordataservice.svc/vDataMapper_SourceMapVendor?&$filter=startswith(ParentName,'AT&T')&$top=7&$skip=0
```

I'm using EF3.5 and SQL2008.  When I send that to my oData service I get no data back.

Comment: Are you producing this yourself? Shouldn't you be encoding that?

Comment: @Craig - That GET string is created by my Telerik control when a filter is applied. Should they be encoding it? I'm not sure, but perhaps.  What other chars should be encoded?  Is it supposed to be HTML encoded?

Comment: The `&` character is reserved in a URI, per the RFC. Yes, it should be encoded.

Comment: Answer helped with my problem as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138561/dynamics-crm-odata-query-that-checks-if-the-file-attachment-file-name-contains Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of characters that should be encoded prior to sending to SQL server over HTTP:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101222238/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx)

Yes, the '&' symbol is one of them.

Answer (score 11):

Do not use the “JavaScript String replace() Method”. It will replace the first occurrence of the special characters. If you have 2 occurance of the same special characters in the filtering parameter, it will fail. So use the regular expression to replace the characters.

```
function replaceSpecialCharacters(attribute) {
  // replace the single quotes
     attribute = attribute.replace(/'/g, "''");

     attribute = attribute.replace(/%/g, "%25");
     attribute = attribute.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
     attribute = attribute.replace(/\//g, "%2F");
     attribute = attribute.replace(/\?/g, "%3F");

     attribute = attribute.replace(/#/g, "%23");
     attribute = attribute.replace(/&/g, "%26");
     return attribute;
}
```

Also pay attention, since the replacements also contains `%` then `%` itself should be replaced at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

if the filter parameter is seen as a single word you can append ASCII value of single quote before and after the param  like this`%27AT&T%27`