# Dynamics CRM: Odata query that checks if the file attachment file name contains the unicode '#'

Tags: unicode, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm

Scenario: I have a custom entity with attachments in Dynamics CRM 2011. I want to query those attachments with file name that contains a hash tag ('#'). Say I have attached a few text documents. kdk#ie.txt, Report.txt, & k!ke.txt to the custom entity.
Here are my results to my Odata query.
Error Code:

//ORGANIATION/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AnnotationSet?$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'{GUID HERE}' and IsDocument eq true and substringof('#',FileName)

Return: Bad Request

Because it is a unicode I tried the following on the string parameter. 
'\u0023'
'U+0021'
'w%u0023'

But return is either 0 or Bad Request

I tested '!' & 'Report' it was successful return 1 respectively. It seem it only does not work for the #.

Any ideas why I am not getting the result I expected?

Really appreciate it.

TIA

Comment: Oh my. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx This answered my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#" sign is a special character in a URL.  It has to be encoded to not create an invalid URL.  [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx](http://%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: I realize you already figured this out, but for SO Completeness, it should not be an unanswered question, since you already have the answer.